# Is there any way to reduce memory consumption to avoid program crash in spacy training?

Tags: spacy

I am working on a nlp project in which i have to deal with large sentences. I am using spacy for that but spacy uses too much memory during training and it fails after some iteration due memory consumption .Is there any way to deal with that?